# How can I invalidate/deinit a NSTimer without doing it in viewWillDisappear?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

```
var faderTimer: NSTimer?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.faderTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.fadeTime, target: self, selector: Selector("fadeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

I need to invalidate this timer before the controller deinits.

```
deinit {
    //never gets called
    if let timer = self.faderTimer {
        self.faderTimer!.invalidate()
        self.faderTimer = nil
    }
}
```

However, I can't stick it in the deinit().  It seems that I have to invalidate it in `viewWillDisappear`.  However, I don't want to do that, because it messes up the background switching.  (Returning from background doesn't call viewWillAppear, so I have to use notifications to start the timer, which is a huge pain.)  I rather just start the timer on viewDidLoad and stop it on deinit().

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what's wrong with doing it in `viewWillDisappear`? It is not called merely because the user backgrounds the app, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I rather just start the timer on `viewDidLoad` and stop it on `deinit()`

Well, you can't. The timer is retaining you (`self`), and will continue to do so until it is invalidated. This means that unless you take action to invalidate the timer elsewhere, `deinit` will never be called *and the view controller will leak* (it will never go out of existence, and all the memory it is holding, along with that of all its properties, will continue to be held). You *must* find another place to invalidate the timer; that's just the way it is.

If you don't like that, *then don't use NSTimer*. Use GCD and `dispatch_source_t` instead. This has the advantage that it is based around a block (a closure) - and you can use `weak self` or `unowned self` inside the block to prevent yourself from being retained, and thus you can invalidate the timer in `deinit` if you want to. That is exactly why I have created a [GCD-based timer class](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p499timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift), as a substitute for NSTimer.

Comment: What's the best place to do it without viewWillDisappear?  The problem is that when I do it there, it does ```not``` get called on background entrance.  Therefore I need to implement notification centers, futher complicating the code.

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is a _great_ place to do it. It is guaranteed to be called when this view controller's view is about to be taken out of the interface, which is exactly what you want to know.

Comment: "The problem is that when I do it there, it does not get called on background entrance" So what? You have not explained what the problem with that is. You go into the background, the timer stops. You come back, the timer runs again. That's not the problem. The problem is what happens when it's time for your view controller to go out of existence - it can't, because the timer is still running and is still retaining it. You _must_ do something about that. That's the nature of NSTimer memory management.

Comment: @matt: Are the github links outdated?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, and they will soon be outdated again! :) Meanwhile, here's the current location for the file referenced in the earlier comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p499timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/FlipsideViewController.swift

Comment: The problem with invalidating the timer in `viewWillDisappear` is that `viewWillDisappear` does not mean the view will be unloaded. If you are popping another view controller from this one, then `viewWillDisappear` will be called even though the view is still technically in existence, but in the background. As soon as you dismiss the new view controller you will go back to the old one, but now your timer is invalidated when maybe it should not yet be.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late but you can invalide it in `viewWillDissappear` like that;

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if isMovingFromParentViewController() {
        yourTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

If `isMovingFromParentViewController` returns true, that means user tap back button and pop to last view controller in navigation stack. So, `deinit` will be called in true place.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! isMovingFromParentViewController is exactly what I needed :)