# deinit not called inside uiviewcontroller after pressing back - Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nstimer, dealloc

I am trying to dealloc / destroy an NSTimer after a user clicks back, but the deinit{...} inside the uiviewcontroller never gets called.

Comment: Note that a running NSTimer *retains* it target and therefore prevents it from being deallocated. That's why deinit is not called. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022298/how-can-i-invalidate-deinit-a-nstimer-without-doing-it-in-viewwilldisappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware that a view controller going out of the screen does not mean that it will be deallocated afterwards. I would recommend moving the timer dealloc to viewDidDisappear, but obviously it depends what you are using that timer for as well.

Comment: viewDidDisappear is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!